# How to output properly linked file-URLs in Terminal Window?

Tags: command-line, bash, caja

I have a script that returns certain file paths, it would be nice if also those containing spaces could be opened with „right-click→open link“:

[image]

```
$> echo file:///home/frank/someOtherFolder/
file:///home/frank/someOtherFolder/
```

→ works as expected (no spaces involbed)

---

```
$> echo file:///home/frank/some Folder/
file:///home/frank/some Folder/
```

underlined Link ends after "some" → broken link

---

```
$> echo file:///home/frank/some%20Folder/
file:///home/frank/some%20Folder/
```

full URL is linked, but “right-click→open link” leads to nothing.

I also tried various quotes around the whole thing or just the path, but no luck....

---

```
echo "file:///home/frank/some\\ Folder"
file:///home/frank/some\ Folder
```

Nice one, eh? But URL also stops after `some\` :-(

Comment: Does it work if you just quote them? `echo '"file:///home/frank/some Folder"'`

Comment: The %20 trick works for me (currently on Fedora, though).

Comment: @vanadium Does it just hover+underline on full length (I got that, too) or does it successfully open the link (that fails with Caja, under Ubuntu-MATE)?

Comment: @terdon: Nope. It sure is written there nicely (same as with `\ `), but no hoverable full link created.

Comment: Then I doubt it will be possible. Just one more reason why it is a very bad idea to have spaces in file or dir names :/

Comment: I had the impression it worked previous time, but not now: the entry indeed is underlined but clicking does nothing. However, right-click - "Open Link" opens nautilus in that directory.